# How to Select a Hover Over Sub Menu

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Webpage: https://www.utepilsbrewing.com/

I'm trying to select one of the Sub Menu Items under Taproom.  My issue is the XPath I'm using for Taproom is not working.  I want to hover over it and select the What's on Tap link

```
Selenium Error: Element: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on windows (9fbd2c11add5470a3628fa96d93eb264)] -> xpath: //*[@id="menu-item-33573"]/a]
```

Here's my code

```
    driver.get("https://www.utepilsbrewing.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/form/div[2]/div/button[1]")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-item-1846\"]/a"));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-item-33573\"]/a")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below code

```java
        import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions; 
 
        driver.get("https://www.utepilsbrewing.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//button[@type='submit'])[1])")).click();

        //Try to use explicit wait 
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement menuItem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//a[text()='Taproom'])[1])"));
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement menuClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//a[text()='Visit Our Taproom'])[1])"));
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(menuItem).click(menuClick).build().perform();
```

Comment: I'm seeing the following error on .click                                                                            The method click(WebElement) is undefined for the type Object

Comment: I needed to add import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions; to get the last line of code to work, but once I did that it fixed my issue